# Infopath Form & Sharepoint Form Library Permissions

Tags: infopath

I have published an infopath form to a Sharepoint 2013 form library however I would like certain permissions setup and cannot figure out how to get it working.

Id like the online form to be available to all users up to the point of submission however once submitted would like to have the users redirected to a different website or a page saying that the form has been submitted.

Currently the form submission takes the user to the form library which we dont want them to see as potentially holds sensitive information.

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Kind Regards,
Chris

Answer (score 1):

I have handled this two separate ways.

1. I used to set up an infopath webpart on a wikipage to only house the form and make the library hidden.
2. In 2013, I do a two library approach. The first a library that submits the form. Then it triggers a workflow to copy it to a secure library and delete it from original library.

There may be better ways of handling this, but this has been my approach in the past.